# How do I trigger the "error" callback in backbone.js collection.create?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

```
collection.create(data, {
    success:function(){ ... },
    error: function(){ ... },
});
```

If I save it, and it hits the server, but the server validates an error, how do I let the client know? It seems that no matter what, "success" is called.

Comment: Use Fiddler to block all traffic.  That'll do it.  (Or shut down the server in some other way.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error callback is triggered on a 4xx or 5xx HTTP response.

What are the HTTP response codes of your server errors?

The [latest Backbone docs](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-save) have a small blurb about this:

> If a server-side validation fails, return a non-200 HTTP response code, along with an error response in text or JSON.

Comment: for example: `def error(object)
    render :json => object, :status => 404
  end`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make the server send a response code of not 200 ok.. like 500.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-save